# SQL Datepart adding year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of dates ranging from starting 1960 to 2016. I want to take the Month and Day of the Date and:

```
   - If Month and Day > Today then add 2016 as Yr BUT
   - If Month and Day < Today then add 2017 as Yr
```

Here is the SQL I have so far:

```
Select DATEPART(MM, Date) as Month,
  DATEPART(dd, Date) as DayNum
  From DateTable
  WHERE CategoryID = 3
```

Comment: can you show how your sample output would look like?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select (case when month(date) * 100 + day(date) < month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate())
             then datefromparts(2017, month(date), day(date)
             else datefromparts(2016, month(date), day(date)
        end) as next_anniversary
from datetable
where categoryid = 3;
```

You don't actually have to do the arithmetic.  This is equivalent:

```
select (case when month(date) < month(getdate()) or
                  month(date) = month(getdate()) and day(date) < day(getdate())
             then datefromparts(2017, month(date), day(date)
             else datefromparts(2016, month(date), day(date)
        end) as next_anniversary
from datetable
where categoryid = 3;
```

Also, `datefromparts()` is available in SQL Server 2012+.  You can cobble together similar functionality in earlier versions of SQL Server, but this is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do it. Works just fine

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(Date AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR),6,10)<SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR),6,10)
THEN datefromparts(2017, month(Date), day(Date))
ELSE datefromparts(2016, month(Date), day(Date)) END
FROM datetable
WHERE categoryid = 3;
```

Let me know if it works for you as well.

Incase your are running SQL Server 2008, `DATEFROMPARTS` won't work, instead use

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(Date AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR),6,10)<SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR),6,10)
THEN DATEADD(YEAR, 2017-YEAR(ex_date), Date)
ELSE DATEADD(YEAR, 2016-YEAR(ex_date), Date)
END
FROM datetable
WHERE categoryid = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query for SQL Server version from 2008.

```
     SELECT CASE WHEN month(date) < =month(getdate())  and day(date) < day(getdate()) 
                   THEN CONVERT(DATE,'2017-'+
                              CAST(Month(date) AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+CAST(Day(date) AS VARCHAR(2)))
                    ELSE CONVERT(DATE,'2016-'+
                             CAST(Month(date) AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+CAST(Day(date) AS VARCHAR(2))) END as new_date
     FROM datetable
     WHERE categoryid = 3;
```